# How to break big graphql schema file into multiple small files?

Tags: graphql

I'm using graphql, express-graphql and mongoose. I'm not using buildSchema.
Below is the code I used to learn graphql and I'm not interested in using apollo-server for right now. The thing is my schema file is getting quite big now and I want to keep things organized better.

How would I break this code up into multiple files?

schema.js:

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const Book = require('../models/book');
const Author = require('../models/author');

const { 
    GraphQLObjectType, 
    GraphQLSchema, 
    GraphQLString, 
    GraphQLID,
    GraphQLInt,
    GraphQLList,
    GraphQLNonNull
 } = graphql;

const BookType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Book',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        genre: { type: GraphQLString },
        author: { 
            type: AuthorType,
            resolve(parent, args) {
                //find(authors, { id: parent.authorID });
                return Author.findById(parent.authorID);
            }
        }
    })
});

const AuthorType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Author',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        age: { type: GraphQLInt },
        books: {
            type: new GraphQLList(BookType),
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return Book.find({ authorID: parent.id });
            }
        }
    })
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        book: {
            type: BookType,
            args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return Book.findById(args.id);
            }
        },
        author: {
            type: AuthorType,
            args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return Author.findById(args.id);
            }
        },
        books: {
            type: new GraphQLList(BookType),
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return Book.find({});
            }
        },
        authors: {
            type: new GraphQLList(AuthorType),
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return Author.find({});
            }
        }
    }
});

const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        addAuthor: {
            type: AuthorType,
            args: {
                name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
                age: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt) }
            },
            resolve(parent, args) {
                let author = new Author({
                    name: args.name,
                    age: args.age
                });
                return author.save();
            }
        },
        addBook: {
            type: BookType,
            args: {
                name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
                genre: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
                authorID: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) }
            },
            resolve(parent, args) {
                let book = new Book({
                    name: args.name,
                    genre: args.genre,
                    authorID: args.authorID
                });
                return book.save();
            }
        }
    }
});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: RootQuery,
    mutation: Mutation
});
```

How I call schema in my app.js:

```
app.use('/api', graphqlHTTP( async req => ({
    schema,
    graphiql: { headerEditorEnabled: true }
})));
```

Answer (score 0):

This can all be boiled down to classic JS imports & exports. Everything you are doing here can be defined and exported in separate files, imported where you need them accordingly. I am not totally sure that I would encourage this way of thinking about your schema, but to answer your question:

You could create the following folder structure:

```
typedefs/bookType.js
typedefs/authorType.js
typedefs/query.js
typedefs/mutation.js
```

This allows you to organize your schema typedefs as smaller, separate, exportable units.

For example, your bookType.js file might look something like this:

```
// Declare your imports at the top
import { AuthorType } from './authorType';
import Author from '../models/author';

// Note the export
export const BookType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Book',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        genre: { type: GraphQLString },
        author: { 
            type: AuthorType,
            resolve(parent, args) {
                //find(authors, { id: parent.authorID });
                return Author.findById(parent.authorID);
            }
        }
    })
});
```

And your author type could look like:

```
import { BookType } from './bookType';
import Book from '../models/Book';
...

export const AuthorType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Author',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        age: { type: GraphQLInt },
        books: {
            type: new GraphQLList(BookType),
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return Book.find({ authorID: parent.id });
            }
        }
    })
});
```

A few things to be aware of:

1. Watch out for circular dependencies. BookType is going to need to import AuthorType, and AuthorType is going to import BookType. Circular dependencies can lead to hard-to-treat bugs, plus can cause heap/memory issues and break typecheckers (like Typescript or FlowType).
2. If you take this approach, your schema becomes harder to reason about. Unlike DB models, where each model/table is its own individual entity with few (if any) dependencies, your GraphQL schema really thrives when it can easily express data interdependencies between types. That's why, given personal experience trying this a few times, I would not encourage this way of writing your schema. See my other post here that elaborates on this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65035430/4301222